# Calling phtml File in CMS Block or In CMS Page

Tags: magento2

Calling phtml File in CMS Block or In CMS Page in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"}}
```

**File Path:** `Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Theme/templates/test.phtml`